# custom post type and a "sticky" position taxonomy

Tags: custom-post-types, wp-query, custom-taxonomy, query-posts, tax-query

I have a custom post type with a custom taxonomy that denotes various types of places the custom post might appear in the site. One that I'm having some trouble with is a "sticky" term for the archive pages. Essentially it should act as you might expect the standard sticky post feature to act on archive pages for this specific custom post type. I'm still trying to work out the best option, but I have this so far.

```
function sticky_posts( $posts, $query ) {
  if ( is_post_type_archive( 'custom-post' ) && $query->is_main_query() && ! is_admin() ) {

    $args = array(
      'post_type' => 'custom-post',
      'post_status' => 'publish',
      'tax_query' => array(
          array(
              'taxonomy' => 'position',
              'field'    => 'slug',
              'terms'    => 'sticky',
          )
      )
  );

  $sticky_posts = new WP_Query( $args );

  foreach( $sticky_posts->posts as $post ) {
    $position = array_search( $post->ID,  wp_list_pluck( $posts, 'ID' ), true );
    $candidate = $posts[ $position ];
    unset( $posts[ $position ] );
    array_unshift( $posts, $candidate );
  }

  }

  return $posts;
}

add_filter( 'posts_results', 'sticky_posts');
```

This doesn't quite work right, as the `posts_results` hook doesn't quite give you everything that is required for this particular implementation of this concept. (I'm not entirely convinced the function actually does what I want but it's what I've got so far.) Suggestions for a better implementation?

Comment: Can you rephrase what you meant by the last 2 sentences? The sentence immediately after the code block doesn't make sense, it looks like the end was cut off as it's never stated what _that this_ is referring to

Comment: Oops! Yep, I see it.

Comment: if it doesn't give you everything that is required, what does it give you instead and what is missing?

Comment: I believe `posts_results` only gives you access to the posts available to a single segment of paginated posts, not the entire query's-worth of posts.

Comment: that to be expected though, and highly desirable, e.g. if there were 10k posts then accessing them would lead to page load times in the tens of minutes, and multi-GB memory footprints for the request. Simply transferring the posts from the database would take more time than most pages take to load. There's a reason the REST API limits posts per page to ~100 then requires pagination to access the rest

Comment: Of course, but I basically need to pull out everything with the sticky taxonomy term and drop it at the top of the query. I'm pretty sure `post_results` won't do that for me.

Comment: there are no filters to do that, that approach does not scale beyond 100 posts on a single page of results